# Do Dart's package_config.json files have a documented format?

Tags: dart, dart-pub

Pub often generates a package resolution configuration file in `.dart_tool/package_config.json`. Is the format of this file documented anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

The Dart Package Configuration File v2.0 format was introduced in Dart 2.8 and is documented in the Dart language repository.

https://github.com/dart-lang/language/blob/main/accepted/2.8/language-versioning/package-config-file-v2.md